# An Arranged Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix bends bridges and branches in dozens.
>
> My suffix sends mail with what one-hundred governs.
>
> My **i**nf**i**x appears three times, hectic and scattered.
>
> I meet engineers, for the looks always mattered.

This might be pretty easy... but that won't receive the $100$ rep bounty award. 
 You would have to find a secret word in this riddle, involving the numbers, if you want that award. 
 The numbers also include $16$.

<sub>I would give out $50$ instead, but it was my birthday recently, so I am being kind :) ***Note:*** This is genuinely true and not part of the riddle.</sub>

---

**Hint:**

> $100=10\times 10$... but that is not necessarily true for Romans.

Comment: Good riddle!  No idea what the answer is, but happy belated birthday! :-)

Comment: @Greg thank you! I was gonna mention my birthday in a riddle that I posted on the same day, but I was a little shy :P

Comment: Hey, happy birthday! :)

Comment: @Mark thank you. I am going to start making some "normal" riddles from now on. I can't think up any more words to make Riley Riddles out of, so I wanted to end on a good note :P

Comment: definitely not easy :P but quite interesting indeed, fun fact, my birthday was a few days ago as well. Belated greetings to you..

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Really? Do you mind my asking of which day your birthday took place? (Also, the last line should give it away... well, that's what I expected.) Oh, and happy birthday to you! (That was rude of me to have not said that in this comment earlier, so sorry about that.)

Comment: It could be the answer to my last riddle, if it were intended for a Chinese foody guy :P and thnx for the wishes

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid **QuantumTwinkie** answered your last riddle, if I am correct. That riddle was really good :D

Comment: yes he did get it right, will be getting the bounty as well..

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid good on him :D

Answer (score 1):

A guess at the non-secret answer.  Are you an

> Architect?

My prefix bends bridges and branches in dozens.

> Bridges are built with arches, and dozens of branches can make arches such as wedding aches

My suffix sends mail with what one-hundred governs.

> (Don't have this yet)

My infix appears three times, hectic and scattered.

> the letters 'i' and 't' appear consecutively 3 times in this riddle, though the order varied.

I meet engineers, for the looks always mattered.

> Architects meet with Engineers to create buildings, with the former providing the looks and the latter providing the saftey/methods

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

Prefix:

> Birds? I'm not sure.

Infix:

> The letters: BGLPWX each appear 3 times in the riddle, one of these could be the infix, as they have different states of scatteredness throughout the riddle.

Suffix:

> The US Senate has 100 members, and they govern the law. The mail may refer to a different spelling: LORE.

Numbers:

> Dozen = 12, one-hundred = 100 = 10 x 10 = XX, two bold i = II = 11, three  = 3, for = 4, includes 16. Turn these into letters of the alphabet: LXXKCDP. <s>Put this through the Caeser Shift Cipher +15: WMNOA. Solve this anagram: WOMAN</s>

Comment: The affixes are way off, but the numbers part is actually quite close. You are in the right direction, but the ii $\neq 2$. So although you might not get the answer, you could get the bounty! But, what is Caesar Shift?

Comment: @user477343 A Caeser Shift is a simple cipher, rot13 is an example of one. it just rotates every letter through the alphabet by a certain amount, in my case, i chose 15.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Well, a caesar shift is definitely required, not not +15 (oh how close, though!) And, the number one is not part of the numbers. It is actually much bigger than that (probably obvious now, heheh).

Comment: @ user477343 And I still haven't got it >_< rot13(V gubhtug vg zvtug or bar uhaqerq naq gurersber P (ebzna ahzrenyf) be Q (NFPVV). Ab vqrn jung gur gjb obyq v'f ersre gb gubhtu vs abg gjb? )

Comment: Is the ii (ROT13) Zrna gur yrggref jrer qrpvcurerq va ebg ryrira. pnhfr vs lbh hfr gur yrggre NEFR lbh va ebg ryrira lbh trg YPQC...

Comment: Try this: (ROT13) Chg gur v'f gb pncvgnyf. Jung ahzore qb lbh frr? Nyfb, gur bar-uhaqerq cneg qbrf ersre gb n P va gur nafjre gb gur Evyrl Evqqyr, ohg abg arprffnevyl gur obhagl nafjre :D

Comment: @gabbo1092 close, but no not quite. Read my above comment :P

Comment: @gabbo1092 if you use rot15 to go one way, then rot11 will be required to go back to the original as there are 26 letters. rot 13 works both ways as it's in the middle of the 26 :)

Comment: @AHKieran yeah I know I had used Rot15 to decode to see what encoded by Rot 11 would be and had got a word but not the right one apparently just a funny coincidence